# Reading FreeBSD UFS formatted external drive in Mac OS X

Tags: filesystems, osx, freebsd, ufs

I have an external USB drive with backup files formatted in FreeBSD's UFS file system. When I plug it into a computer running Mac OS X 10.9.4, I cannot read the drive's contents, and I don't have physical access to a machine running FreeBSD.

Is there a way to read this drive on a Mac? I only need read-only mode to copy the files to the local filesystem.

Thanks.

Comment: If osxfuse doesn't work, I'd boot a freebsd live cd on another computer (or a VM), plug in that external drive, mount the filesystems, and scp the files to the Mac.

Comment: FreeBSD in a virtualbox instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this tutorial. It's untested by me but several commenters to the article attested to it working. The article is titled: [Mount a ufs2 Volume in MacOS/X 10.7 (Lion)](https://wiki.gutzmann.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6651931).

*excerpt*

> If you have to mount an ufs2 volume (for example an external FreeNAS
>   disk) in MacOS/X Lion, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Download and install OSXFUSE from http://osxfuse.github.com/. Reboot the system.
> 2. Download this ZIP file from https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems.
> 3. Download and install XCode from http://developer.apple.com/xcode/. This is a prerequisite for step 10.
>
>    - Download and install XCode.
>    - Launch XCode.
>    - Open XCode preferences.
>    - Go to tab "Downloads".
>    - Locate "Command Line Tools".
>    - Click "Install" and enter your credentials.
> 4. Locate the directory `unixfs` in the unzipped source code downloaded in step 2.
> 5. Open a terminal window.
> 6. Enter `sudo -s` and supply your admin password.
> 7. Copy `unixfs` (see step 4) to `/usr/local/include/osxfuse/` (`cp -R unixfs /usr/local/include/osxfuse/`).
> 8. Enter `cd /usr/local/include/osxfuse/unixfs/ufs`.
> 9. Enter `ln -s /usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse`.
> 10. Enter `make`.
> 11. Create a mount point, for example `mkdir usb`.
> 12. Enter `diskutil list` and look for the identifier of the external drive containing the UFS volume (for me it was "disk1s1").
> 13. Enter `./ufs --dmg /dev/disk1s1 --type ufs2 usb`, replacing "disk1s1" with the actual identifier under "usb" with the mount point created in step 11.
> 14. Enter `df -h` to see if the volume has been mounted.
>
> **Additional Notes**
>
> - The ufs2 volume will be mounted read-only.
> - I didn't find a way to see the volume in the Finder, not even with "Go to Folder...", so I had to copy the files I wanted to work with
>     using a command like `cp -R macHOTEL /Users/gutzmtho/Downloads`. It
>     didn't help to create the mount point in `/Volumes`. As pointed out in
>     one of the comments below: "You can see it in Finder, when you are
>     logged in as root user." (thanks to the contribution!)
> - Another option is to set up a virtual machine inside the Mac, for example FreeBSD or Ubuntu. There you see the files in the Finder
>     equivalent of Linux, but copying files across is awkward because
>     ".AppleDouble" files will not be copied - at least using drag and
>     drop, unless you make files starting with a "." visible.

Comment: Step 10 fails for me on OS X 10.8.5. I get an error about an unused function. If I remove the function, I get some syntax errors.

Comment: @9000 - please post the error msgs you've encountered.

Comment: Here's what I see when I run `make`: ufs.c:759:1: error: unused function 'ufs_validate_entry'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-function]
ufs_validate_entry(struct super_block* sb, char* base, unsigned offset,
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [ufs.o] Error 1

Comment: @9000 - post this on the osxfuse's issue tracker, here: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues

Comment: Isn't it more suitable to post it in the osxfuse/filesystems issue tracker? I've put it there for now.

Comment: @9000 - I don't think that matters that much, let the project determine where they want to track it, reporting it at the top is what I'd typically do.